# How can I configure apache to use https instead of http for some requests?

Tags: linux, apache-http-server, http, https

For some of the files that I share using Apache, I want to make sure that they are served ONLY via https.

How can I configure this for Apache?

Answer (score 1):

Use the Rewrite Engine module.  Instructions can be found here:

Apache: Redirect http to https Apache secure connection – force HTTPS Connections
  http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/howto-apache-force-https-secure-connections.html